# Twitter API authenticating failing

Tags: api, rest, twitter, postman

I have downloaded postman collection of Twitter API and set all the required keys in environment variables.

When I try to run following URL ,

```
https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/search/all?query=%23haiku
```

I am getting following error in postman.

```
{
"client_id": "22929871",
"detail": "When authenticating requests to the Twitter API v2 endpoints, you must use keys and tokens from a Twitter developer App that is attached to a Project. You can create a project via the developer portal.",
"registration_url": "https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/projects/overview",
"title": "Client Forbidden",
"required_enrollment": "Standard Basic",
"reason": "client-not-enrolled",
"type": "https://api.twitter.com/2/problems/client-forbidden"
}
```

For following API, I am getting response.

```
https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/search/recent?query=%23haiku
```

Can someone suggest me, what I am missing.

Comment: did you read the detail message?

Comment: Yes, Can you suggest me how can I elevate to this level ?

Comment: Did you read the information about that endpoint in the Postman collection, and do you have Academic access to the Twitter API?